# WPF user control, access dependency properties of component elements

Tags: wpf, xaml

#### Problem

A user WPF control is made up of multiple standard controls.

How can multiple dependency properties of the component (base or standard) controls be accessed in XAML, when implementing the parent (user) control, *without creating additional properties*?

#### Details

What do I mean by "creating additional dependency properties"? Well, that is the only way I know of accessing properties of the component controls: by implementing attached properties, as described at MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Anchor_2).

However, it presents the following problems:

- Existing dependency properties must be copied as new properties, defeating the DRY principle.
- If data binding is to occur, more work must be done to bind existing dependency properties to the new exposed dependency properties.

I'm wondering if there is a way to "walk" the base controls within the user control, to access their properties - from within XAML.

#### Example

For example, I make a user WPF control that inherits from `UserControl`. It is simple - it consists of a `StackPanel` containing a `Label` and a `TextBlock`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.CustomControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Name="BaseLabel">Label Here</Label>
        <TextBlock Name="BaseTextBlock">Some text here.</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Now, when I use my `UserControl` elsewhere in XAML, I'm wishfully thinking something like this could be done to edit my `Label`'s content... although I don't know of a way:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp">
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- This won't work, don't try at home kids. -->
        <local:CustomControl BaseLabel.Content="I did it!"></local:CustomControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Much thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I originally wrote "custom control" throughout this question - it's actually a "user control" to use Microsoft's terminology. The two are different things.

Comment: If the user control should be reusable, how about creating a reusable view-model for it as well? That allows you to use bindings in the user control, and the only thing the parent view needs to do is to set the `DataContext` - which would be a property of the parent view's view-model.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet: good idea for when control will be reused with the same model. However wouldn't the view-model (and the control itself) have to be redesigned if re-used across multiple solutions, with different models? I'm just thinking that wouldn't provide the same flexibility as the factory controls, with their many dependency properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the next solution:
 1. Create the AttachedProperty (because you must an entry point) and bind this property to the collection of data.This collection of data will contain changes you want perform on sub-controls of a main user control used inside the window. This collection will be defined inside the main window  view model.
 2. In attached property changed callback get the binded collection, parse it data into sub-controls properties.
Here is the solution:
 3. Xaml code:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <nirHelpingOvalButton:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <nirHelpingOvalButton:InnerControl x:Name="MyInnerControl" 
                                       nirHelpingOvalButton:Helper.InnerControlPropertiesAccessor="{Binding InnerData, Mode=Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

4. Attached property code (bindig support):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerControlPropertiesAccessorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "InnerControlPropertiesAccessor", typeof (ObservableCollection<TargetControlData>), typeof (Helper), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<TargetControlData>), InnerValueAccessProviderPropertyChangedCallback));

    public static void SetInnerControlPropertiesAccessor(DependencyObject element, ObservableCollection<TargetControlData> value)
    {
        element.SetValue(InnerControlPropertiesAccessorProperty, value);
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<TargetControlData> GetInnerControlPropertiesAccessor(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<TargetControlData>) element.GetValue(InnerControlPropertiesAccessorProperty);
    }
    private static void InnerValueAccessProviderPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var control = sender as Control;
        if (control == null) return;
        var valuesMap = args.NewValue as ObservableCollection<TargetControlData>;
        if (valuesMap == null)
            return;
        valuesMap.ToList().ForEach(data => TryToBind(control, data));
    }

    private static void TryToBind(Control control, TargetControlData data)
    {
        var innerControl = control.FindName(data.SubControlName) as DependencyObject;
        if (innerControl == null) return;

        var myBinding = new Binding
        {
            Source = data,
            Path = new PropertyPath("Data"),
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        };
        var descriptors = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(innerControl);
        var propertyDescriptor = descriptors.Find(data.SubConrolProperty, true);
        var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(propertyDescriptor);
        if (descriptor == null) return;
        var dependencyProperty = descriptor.DependencyProperty;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(innerControl, dependencyProperty, myBinding);
    }
```

5. Inner control xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NirHelpingOvalButton.InnerControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UniformGrid>
    <Button x:Name="InnerControlButton"></Button>
    <TextBlock x:Name="InnerContentTextBlock"></TextBlock>
</UniformGrid>
```

6. ViewModel code:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    private static int _staticCount = 0;
    private List<Brush> _list = new List<Brush> {Brushes.Green, Brushes.Red, Brushes.Blue};

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        InnerData = new ObservableCollection<TargetControlData>
        {
            new TargetControlData
            {
                SubControlName = "InnerControlButton",
                SubConrolProperty = "Content",
                Data = "Click Me",
            },
            new TargetControlData
            {
                SubControlName = "InnerControlButton",
                SubConrolProperty = "Command",
                Data = new RelayCommand(CommandMethod),
            },
            new TargetControlData
            {
                SubConrolProperty = "Text",
                SubControlName = "InnerContentTextBlock",
                Data = "Hello"
            },
            new TargetControlData
            {
                SubConrolProperty = "Background",
                SubControlName = "InnerContentTextBlock",
                Data = Brushes.Green
            },
            new TargetControlData
            {
                SubConrolProperty = "Foreground",
                SubControlName = "InnerContentTextBlock",
                Data = Brushes.White
            },
        };
    }

    private void CommandMethod()
    {
        _staticCount ++;
        var backgroundData = InnerData.FirstOrDefault(data => data.SubControlName == "InnerContentTextBlock" && data.SubConrolProperty == "Background");
        var textData = InnerData.FirstOrDefault(data => data.SubControlName == "InnerContentTextBlock" && data.SubConrolProperty == "Text");
        if (backgroundData == null || textData == null) return;
        var index = _staticCount%_list.Count;
        backgroundData.Data  = _list[index];
        textData.Data = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Hello", backgroundData.Data);
    }
    public ObservableCollection<TargetControlData> InnerData { get; set; }}
```

7. TargetControlData code:

```
    public class TargetControlData:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _subControlName;
    private string _subConrolProperty;
    private object _data;

    public string SubControlName
    {
        get { return _subControlName; }
        set
        {
            _subControlName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string SubConrolProperty
    {
        get { return _subConrolProperty; }
        set
        {
            _subConrolProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public object Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

8. Summary - you can pull control properties data from configuration file, or collect them by reflection.

regards,

Answer (score -1):

The way you suggested - I don't think this would be possible. 
But it can be done with normal properties, instead of dependency properties, something like:

UserControl xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbOne"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbTwo" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

UserControl code behind:

```
    public string One
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tbOne.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tbOne.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public string Two
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tbTwo.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tbTwo.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

and the usage of user control:

```
    <local:UserControl1 One="test1" Two="test2"></local:UserControl1>
```

Comment: Um, doesn't this answer involve creating additional properties - strings one and two? Also I don't think data binding can occur unless the properties are dependency properties.

Comment: Voting down - thanks for input, but this doesn't answer the question or engage the problems presented by the question. Please let me know if you have any feedback.

Comment: Mhm, didn't you asked about a solution without *dependency* properties? There you have. As with no dependencies *at all*, I guess you would have to write your own markup extension or attached dependency property to the UserControl base class.

Comment: No, I was looking for a solution that didn't create additional properties at all. Instead I'm looking to use the existing dependency properties of the component controls.