# Draw bitmaps on window and update them 'x' times per second

Tags: c#, wpf

Im new in Wpf C# programming and have maybe a stupid question.
I have a form and I need to create some controls with dynamic names.
(For Ex.: Grid: 'main' Controls: "str"+(int)i)
And I need to set Property Margin of this Controls OnTick.
So, Ik how to add this Controls, but have some problems in changing their properties.

Some code:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/img.png"));
img.Name = "str_" + i;
img.Margin = new Thickness(-10,-10,0,0);
img.Width = 1;
img.Height = 2;
main.Children.Add(img);
// ToDo Something like this:
main["str_"+i].Margin = new Thickness(x,y,0,0);
```

So, the question is: How to Edit property of already Created Dynamic control?

---

**Update.
I found it rather stupid to create tons of controls except of refreshing drawings.**

Now I have no idea what is the best way of drawing bitmaps on form.
For example:

- I have List of locations of bitmaps.
- I need to update the
  bitmap's locations 'x' times per second.

Comment: If you keep reference to the img (or other ui elements) in your class, you could change the properties later like you set them here. Or you could use binding which you can google or use the search panel to find out how :)

Comment: Can you, please, add some examples?
Can't understand a bit

Comment: If you post your code (or simplified example) I can be more specific, If I understood you correctly your only problem at the moment is setting control's properties, so I imagine you have the rest of the code in place.

Comment: I have edited the code in question.

Comment: Sorry but for me it's not clear what your intentions are... In the provided example you only create an image and add it to main which I imagine is some grid control ... don't see any timers etc ... please explain what you want to do or post more code to be able to guess something ...

Comment: Yeah, its a grid. I have added to it an Image and then after adding I wanna set a Property Margin.

Comment: OK if it's 1 image only -> in your class you have a field or property `public Image MyImage { get; set; }` then where you generate it change img to MyImage so: `MyImage = new Image();` (not a new variable). Then in your method `MyImage.Margin = new Thickness(x,y,0,0)`

Comment: Okey, thank you, I will try it :3

Answer (score 0):

Look at the next solution. Here is the code that references to the properties of an existing controls by it's (control's) name. It changes the control's set of properties according to the set of properties you support in view model (or code behind). If you will be interested I can make the adaptation to achieve your set of requirements. Here is the link
[WPF user control, access dependency properties of component elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239270/wpf-user-control-access-dependency-properties-of-component-elements/33241457#33241457) .

regards,