# Access elements properties/events inside Usercontrol's

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a usercontrol with a textbox and a label in it like that:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GabrielControls.TextBoxPlaceholder"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GabrielControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="23" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Height="23">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="Textbox1" />
        <Label Name="Label1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Is there a way to access all properties/events of the elements inside the usercontrol directly, like

```
<gc:TextBoxPlaceholder TextBox1.Text="Some text" 
    Label1.Foreground="White" TextBox1.TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
```

Or do i have to expose every property that i want to use and bind it accordingly?

Comment: You cannot do that. You can declare `Resources`, and set properties accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the SO query that helps you to deal with the problem you explain here. The best practice is to provide the resources to each visual binding (like brushes, stroke thicknesses etc) and share Models behind the ViewModels you have in order to get the DataBindings, but when you deal with a completely closed UserControl's that cannot be used apart with the best wpf practices, you can apply workarounds. [Here is the code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239270/wpf-user-control-access-dependency-properties-of-component-elements/33241457#33241457)

I'll glad to help if you will have problems with the code.
Regards.